# Solfege not working for me

Tags: ear-training, solfege

I am taking some ear training lessons and we started out with singing One,Two....
Well, that didn't really work. Now we are trying solfege, but that seems to be just as bad. Many years ago i was trying to just use different "La"'s. I was able to learn my ascending perfect fifth that way. But starting over I thought I would just try whats usually taught in a classroom. Should I go back to what works ? And has anyone else tried solfege to go on to something else that they feel worked better for them ?
Thanks

Comment: All the methods are just paths to 'knowing' the intervals and where notes lie in relation to each other. Your class teacher should choose a system and stick to it.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Do what works for you. Who cares what others are doing if that works.  I have tried solfege and it works for me because I had to do it a million times. But what matters is hearing the intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Solfege itself isn't clear. There are two distinctly different versions.

The one most used in U.K. is *moveable do*, which says that do is *always the root of the key*. Thus the song from the Sound of Music, which actually explains it very well, and might help your cause. 'Cause it really doesn't matter what key it's sung in. And the intervals will always be the same.  Do > sol, a P5, will be the same interval in Eb as it is in A, or C. I'd better add only in 12edo!

The other, used in Europe, particularly France, is *fixed do*, where do is *always C*, no matter what key the piece is in. That works pretty well for singing in C, But as soon as the music is in a different key, 'bemol' (b) or 'diese' (#) needs to be sung after the solfege name to get it correct. Awkward when sight-singing!

A common way that works for many is to remember two notes from a song that produce a specific interval. 'Chasing Cars' intro. is a nice simple P5, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I, as a long time choir member, think that yes, it is hard to get the notes in tune. I have tried both methods, but I prefer solfege. As for your issue, try just listening to it over and over. That will get it in your memory. Then sing it A LOT. This will get that la into your muscle memory. Good luck!